# is there an easy way to get the http status code in the failure block from AFHTTPClient?

Tags: afnetworking

I see that there is a list of accepted http status codes that I can modify, but I think it would be cleaner if I can get the http status code in the failure block ..

Ok, found the answer with the operation object

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){ 
        NSLog(@"error code %d",[operation.response statusCode]);
}];
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Ok, found the answer with the operation object

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){ 
       NSLog(@"error code %d",[operation.response statusCode]);
}];
```

Comment: This might be also helpful `[operation.request HTTPMethod]`

Comment: I know this is old, but @wilhelmbot -- HTTPMethod would give you something like GET/POST/PUT... etc, probably not helpful for checking response status.

Answer (score 112):

In newer versions of AFNetworking, you can retrieve the response object from the error:

```
[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey] statusCode]
```

This is handy if you're doing error handling further up the line and don't want to pass around the response object.

Comment: You might need to get the underlying error first. `NSError *underlyingError = error.userInfo[@"NSUnderlyingError"]`

Answer (score 19):

**For AFNetworking 3.0**, use

```
failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)operation.response;
    httpResponse.statusCode;
    NSLog(@"status code: %li", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> NSInteger operationStatusCode = [operation.error code];
>
> NSInteger httpStatusCode = operation.response.statusCode;

If the requests were cancelled/unreachable/timeout, `httpStatusCode` will be always `0`.

Alternatively you can identify the issue by understanding the `operationStatusCode`. It is a `NSError` Object.

- If it cannot reach/timeout/no network to process request, the `operationStatusCode` will be `-1009`.
- If you cancel the operations queue the `operationStatusCode` will be `-999`.

You can check all other `NSError` codes and their descriptions in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSError_Codes)

Answer (score 7):

### I've been able to get the status code with Swift 3:

```
((error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey])
    as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me 
Add below line to your request

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];